# Algorithm for calculating tree layout with incremental updates

Tags: trees

I am looking for an algorithm that calculates positions of nodes in a non-binary tree. The positions in that layout will be used for drawing the tree. I am using the tree in a mind map application. Currently I use algorithm by C. Buchheim et al, "Improving Walker's Algorithm to Run in Linear Time" (2002). Unfortunately, the algorithm does not support updates of the tree and needs to re-calculate the whole layout after adding a new node to the tree. This will not work well with mind mapping use case where you add new nodes very frequently.

Is there an algorithm that supports scenarios when new nodes added to the tree and uses existing layout information for small update?

Comment: Give the user a "redraw" button that lets them run Walker's Algorithm on-demand.

Comment: @robert-harvey  The problem is in calculating coordinates of new nodes. When you add a new node to the existing tree you need to know where to put it on the screen (x,y). This is the exact job of that algorithm.

Comment: Why don't you let them put it on the screen where they want to put it, or simply find an empty space?